# Scrollbar HTML?

Tags: html, scrollbar

Okay, I'm not entirely sure how to explain this.. but I will, best that I can.

Okay, So I have this Website that I am working on, and uhh. It over-scrolls.

It's extremely annoying, considering there is nothing there for it to scroll.

[here](http://scaryy.webs.com/), maybe this will better explain it.

 I just want to find out how to lock the scroll bar in the **MAIN WINDOW.**

 Not the text-box. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could somehow help me out.

Answer (score 1):

use your browser's developer tool to inspect the DOM.

there's a huge center element below

and also, right click->view source:

your code starts with:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Q u e b e c.-</TITLE>
<style type="text/css"> body { direction:rtl; } </style></HEAD>
<BODY>
<body><html>.... your html code
```

Answer (score 0):

increase the size of the HEIGHT: 300px; to 400px; of the div.... or whatever can accomodate the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different `body` elements. Change your first five lines of code to this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Q u e b e c.-</title>
<style type="text/css"> body { direction:rtl; } </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#969EAF">
// your content here
```

As for your actual issue, you can just set the body's overflow to hidden:

```
body {
  direction:rtl;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

It always helps to pass your code through a validator. It spots all the issues and makes it easier for you to fix them. Looking at your source code right now, there is A LOT you can do to improve it.